# protractor with 2 frameworks in config

Tags: protractor

I use protractor with cucumber and I would like to specify to frameworks in config file: "jasmine" and "custom". Is it possible? Below doesn;t work

```
exports.config = {
  framework: ['jasmine','custom']
```

Please help me out

Comment: why do you need 2 frameworks?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I need to run both Jasmine and Cucumber tests.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration, the `framework` property is of type string and it is not an array string.

```
  /**
   * Test framework to use. This may be one of: jasmine, mocha or custom.
   * Default value is 'jasmine'
   *
   * When the framework is set to "custom" you'll need to additionally
   * set frameworkPath with the path relative to the config file or absolute:
   *
   *   framework: 'custom',
   *   frameworkPath: './frameworks/my_custom_jasmine.js',
   *
   * See github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/frameworks/README.md
   * to comply with the interface details of your custom implementation.
   *
   * Jasmine is fully supported as test and assertion frameworks.
   * Mocha has limited support. You will need to include your
   * own assertion framework (such as Chai) if working with Mocha.
   */
  framework?: string;
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L620